# How to lock a Startup file in LTS Blender 3.3

Tags: startup-file

I have created a custom blender start up and want to freeze the script so that other colleague’s doesn’t messup and save/ overwrite the startup file.
Is there any way to Lock/ Freeze the startup file?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Maybe try to change the write permissions on the file. What OS are you using?

Comment: i am using Windows 10 OS

Comment: Your startup file is located under `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\ `  *> version > config* then just google how to change file permissions on the `startup.blend` file and also make a backup of it.